# SUM() on all rows of a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I've been playing with LEFT JOINs and I'm wondering if it's possible to get the SUM of all the ratings so far from all users in the below query. The below get's me the information on if the logged in user has rated or not, but i want to show total ratings from other users also.

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT com.comment, com.comment_id, r.rate_up, r.rate_down
FROM comments com
LEFT JOIN ratings r
ON com.comment_id = r.comment_id
AND r.user_id = '" . $user_id_var . "'
WHERE page_id = '" . $category_id_var. "'");
```

I've tried the following but i only get one comment/row returned for some reason.

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT com.comment, com.comment_id,
r.rate_up, r.rate_down 
SUM(r.rate_up) AS total_up_ratings, 
SUM(r.rate_down) AS total_down_ratings,
FROM comments com
LEFT JOIN ratings r
ON com.comment_id = r.comment_id
AND r.user_id = '" . $user_id_var . "'
WHERE page_id = '" . $category_id_var. "'");
```

Any help appreciated. Do i need a different kind of JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `GROUP BY page_id` on the end of your SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an aggregation function in SQL (like `SUM()`) you will need a corresponding `GROUP BY` clause.

In your case the most likely one would be `com.comment_id`; this will give you the sum of all ratings per `comment_id`:

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

```
SELECT 
    com.comment, 
    com.comment_id,
    Total.total_down_ratings,
    Total.total_up_ratings
FROM comments com
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT
    SUM(r.rate_up) AS total_up_ratings, 
    SUM(r.rate_down) AS total_down_ratings,
    r.comment_id
FROM
    ratings r
GROUP BY
    r.comment_id
) AS Total
ON com.comment_id = Total.comment_id
AND r.user_id = '" . $user_id_var . "'
WHERE page_id = '" . $category_id_var. "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are duplicating comment rows for purpose but if not you can try write subselect for ratings like this:

```
select comment_id, user_id, sum(rate_up) as sum_rate_up, 
sum(rate_down) as sum_rate_down from ratings 
group_by comment_id, user_id;
```

and then include it in your join query:

```
select com.comment, com.comment_id, r.user_id, r.sum_rate_up, 
r.sum_rate_down from comments com 
left join (select comment_id, user_id, sum(rate_up) as sum_rate_up, 
sum(rate_down) as sum_rate_down from ratings 
group_by comment_id, user_id) as r 
on com.comment_id = r.comment_id where page_id = '".$category_id_var."'
```

Comment: This seems to come the closest so far. The functions i need are to display if the current user has rated a comment, and the total up and down ratings of everyone who's ever rated that comment. Inserting or removing the 'where user_id = '".$user_id_var."'' seems to get one or the other...but not both.

Comment: check edited queries: I've added `group by comment_id, user_id` so in subselect you have ratings of comment for each user that rate this comment. Whole query should give you all comments and information abount users that rated those comments. You can then search in result rows for current user to see if he rated specific comment.

Comment: Still no luck. Wouldn't the query need the users id in there too somewhere?